# How to get welcome page from spring controller on application loading

Tags: spring-mvc

am trying to get the first page on application loading. i have created maven project which is running fine under web-app i have created one folder called jsp inside jsp folder i have created login.jsp
instead of index.jsp it should pick login.jsp which is under jsp folder

[image]
**web.xml**

```
 <welcome-file-list>   
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>   
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
        </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**controller**

```
package com.sanria.estimodelling.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.sanria.estimodelling.dto.LoginDTO;

@Controller
public class SampleController {
    /* Method to return to login page */
    @RequestMapping(value = "login")
    public ModelAndView display() {
        LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO();
        return new ModelAndView("page-login", "login", loginDTO);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code like this its working fine can anyone review this correct me if i am worng??

**Web.xml**

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml
            </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

**Controller**

```
package com.sanria.estimodelling.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.sanria.estimodelling.dto.LoginDTO;

@Controller
public class SampleController {
    /* Method to return to login page */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView display() {
        LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO();
        return new ModelAndView("page-login", "login", loginDTO);
    }
}
```